# Beginner in Angular. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following a tutorial in Youtube...I believe I did everything correct, but it's refuses to work...On the video @ youtube it's works like a charme, but I can't make it works locally. Any clue ? There is no error or even result on the screen. It's just a blank page.

in my controller.js...

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
//Routes
demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/view1',
    {
        controller : 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl : 'view1.html'
    })
    .otherWise('/',
    {
        redirectTo : '/view1'
    });
});

//Controllers
demoApp.controller('SimpleController' , function ($scope) {
    $scope.familyArray = [
    { name : 'Me ', city : 'London'},
    {name : 'Wife', city : 'St. Matheus'},
    {name : 'Son', city : 'Ipswich'}
];
});
```

in my index.html. I've...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div data-ng-view="">

    </div>
</div>
    <script src="./css_and_js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./css_and_js/controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

..And for last, this is my view1.html...

```
<div class="container">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" data-ng-model=filter."nameInput"><br><br>
Hello, {{name}}
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="data in familyArray | filter : filter.nameInput | orderBy: 'city'">{{data.name}} - {{data.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>
Add Name : <br>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="new.name">
<br>
</ul>
Add City : <br>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="new.city">
<br>
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
```

Also, I've no idea how to debug it...on my Chrome console, it's just show : Uncaught object 
at angular.min.js:6

**Update**...After receive some suggestions to change my code...Actually I'm facing a blank page result with no error message on the console. Let me update the code:

controller.js:
    `var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);
    //Routes
    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1',
        {
            controller : 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl : 'view1.html'
        })
        .otherwise('/',
        {
            redirectTo : '/view1'
        });
    });
    //Controllers
    demoApp.controller('SimpleController' , function ($scope) {
    $scope.familyArray = [
        { name : 'Marco Jr', city : 'London'},
        {name : 'Rosana Valkovics', city : 'São Matheus'},
        {name : 'Fernando Valkovics', city : 'Ipswich'}
    ];
    });`

my view1.html:

```
`<div class="container">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.nameInput"><br><br>
Hello, {{name}}
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="data in familyArray | filter : filter.nameInput | orderBy: 'city'">{{data.name}} - {{data.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>
Add Name : <br>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="new.name">
<br>
</ul>
Add City : <br>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="new.city">
<br>
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>`
```

My index.html: No changes.

Actually there is no exceptions, but I'm still facing the blank page :(

Comment: don't use the minified version of angular for development. does your angular.js file include the route module?

Answer (score 1):

Angular works with HTML5. You have the wrong doctype. You need:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Also, take `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` out of your html tag.

Regarding debugging, you should never use the minified version of anything for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your view1.html, line 3. The quotation marks are in the wrong position on the data-ng-model as they should surround all of "filter.nameInput".

Comment: It's indeed a error ! TYVM !!! However I'm still facing the same results :( Soon or late I believe I can solve everything with your help and the help of the others guys ! ty !

Answer (score 0):

If your video is old, and you are using a new version of Angular.js you probably don't have `$routeProvider`. At some point, the angular team broke `$routeProvider` out of the core `angular.js` file and put it into a separate module called `ngRoute`.

You need to change your module definition like so:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[ngRoute]);
```

And you need to include the `angular-route.js` script tag.

```
<script src="./css_and_js/angular-route.js">
```

Here's some additional info on [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Comment: ty !! Just like the Edward answer :) I believe that's the correct way..I'm still facing issues...but I'm thankful to get a good guidance !

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several mistakes and wrong assumptions.

New versions of angular require ngRoute to be declared as a dependency.

Dependencies:

you have to add it to your index.html
for example:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular-route.js"></script>
```

and declare the dependency in the module:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);
```

It will still not work because you have a syntax error

```
.otherWise('/',
```

should be

```
.otherwise('/',
{
    redirectTo : '/view1'
});
```

You can see it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j6TGJ/)

Comment: Hey, ty !!! There is no exception anymore..However it's still show a black page :( even in the fiddle, there is no result :( But I really appreciate it anyway :)

Comment: The fiddle has no index.html... please be specific.  What is 'an issue'? Can you use 'hello world' in the partials instead of complex angular syntax?

Comment: as i told..the issue is a blank screen. A simple blank screen - no trace of anything regarding view1.